# System not able to find file with space while calculating md5/sha1

Tags: python

I have written below code to generate hash code for all mp3 files available in a directory. But system is throwing error for files having space in name

directory - d:\song

Files in the directory AB CD.mp3, Abc.mp3, GB.mp3

```
import os

dirname = 'd:\song'

def walk(dirname):
    names = []
    for name in os.listdir(dirname):
        path = os.path.join(dirname,name)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            names.append(path)
        else:
            names.extend(walk(path))
    return names

def chk_dup(f):
    for i in f:
        cmd = 'fciv -md5 %s' % i.replace(' ','')
        fp = os.popen(cmd)
        res = fp.read()
        print(res)
        fp.close()

chk_dup(walk(dirname))
```

Output is

```
//
// File Checksum Integrity Verifier version 2.05.
//
d:\song\abcd.mp3\*

    Error msg  : The system cannot find the path specified.

    Error code : 3

//
// File Checksum Integrity Verifier version 2.05.
//
1a65b4c63d64f0634c1411d37629be3b d:\song\abc.mp3

//
// File Checksum Integrity Verifier version 2.05.
//
bbf47eb1cb3625eea648f0b6e0784fd3 d:\song\gb.mp3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably fix your immediate problem by enclosing all the file path name arguments in double quotes in case they contain spaces. This will make it be treated it as a single argument rather than two (or more) of them which is the case otherwise.

```
    for i in f:
        cmd = 'fciv -md5 "%s"' % i
        ...
```

However, rather than just do that, I would suggest that you stop using`os.popen()`altogether, because [it has been deprecated since Python version 2.6](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#file-object-creation), and use the recommended`subprocess` module instead. Among other advantages, doing so will automatically handle the quoting of arguments with spaces in them for you.

In addition it would also be useful for you to take advantage of the built-in`os.walk()`function to simplify your own`walk()`function.

Incorporating both of these changes would result in code looking something like the following:

```
import os
import subprocess

directory = r'd:\song'

def walk(dirname):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirname):
        for name in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, name)
            yield path

def chk_dup(files):
    for file in files:
        args = ['fciv', '-md5', file]  # cmd as sequence of arguments
        p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        res = p.communicate()[0]  # communicate returns (stdoutdata, stderrdata)
        print res

chk_dup(walk(directory))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file is `"AB CD.mp3"`, no `"ABCD.mp3"`. Therefore, the file `"ABCD.mp3"` cannot be found.

Try to use `'` to fill the command:

```
cmd = "fciv -md5 '%s'" % i
```

Comment: with new syntax it is not working for a single file and throwing error filename/directorname syntax is incorrect error code 7b while fciv -md5 'AB CD.mp3' working perfectly on commandline

Comment: @VishalTyagi Test `cmd = 'fciv -md5 "%s"' % i`